# Limit API requests (compute.instances.listReferrers)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer

I need some help limiting requests to one of my Google Cloud instances - it looks like someone is making about 10-15 requests per second which is preventing me from ssh'ing into my instances.

I looked into which API requests are being made and it's all of the form (compute.instances.listReferrers), which seems to be listing all of the other instances in the same zone. I'm unclear why the request has been made over 200,000 times and don't think any of the code I've written anywhere should be making this request. I was doing a couple of scp's but they should all have terminated and none are still active.

How do I prevent someone from making this request or require authentication?

Comment: Provide more information on how you are determining this (API Dashboard?). To make the API call `compute.instances.listReferrers` requires that the other party has an IAM member account with authorization in your Project or a Google service that is managing/monitoring your account. A normal account will have thousands (tens, hundreds, millions) of API requests but the key metric is API requests per second which in normal usage is one per second - depends on how many resources are in your account. 10 -15 is not that unusual, a bit high if you only have one resource.

Comment: Look in Stackdriver logs for the IAM member account making this request and disable their account in IAM or remove their Compute Engine Role. However, making this request will NOT affect your ability to SSH into your instance. Your instance does not process Google Cloud API calls. API calls are handled/routed by the Google Frontend Service (GFE).

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense. I checked it out and it seems to have been a normal amount of traffic. Thank you for the quick replies!